# Invalid use of non-static member function c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am following this [example](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1). But when I compile, it returns an error:

> Invalid use of non-static member function

at the line

```
void(Machine:: *ptrs[])() = 
  {
    Machine::off, Machine::on
  };
```

I tried to add `static` to  `void on();` at class

```
class Machine
{
  class State *current;
  public:
    Machine();
    void setCurrent(State *s)
    {
        current = s;
    }
    static void on(); // I add static here ...
    static void off(); // and here
};
```

But it complains that

> Invalid use of member Machine::current in static member function

Can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlike static member functions or free functions, non-static member functions won't [implicitly convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer) to member function pointers.

(emphasis mine)

> An lvalue of function type `T` can be implicitly converted to a prvalue pointer to that function. **This does not apply to non-static member functions** because lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist.

So you need to use `&` explicitly to take the address of the non-static member functions (i.e. to get non-static member function pointers). e.g.

```
void(Machine:: *ptrs[])() = 
  {
    &Machine::off, &Machine::on
  };
```

If you declare them as static member function, you should change the type of `ptrs` (to array of non-member function pointers). Note that for static member function it's fine to not use `&` explicitly. e.g.

```
void(*ptrs[])() = 
  {
    Machine::off, Machine::on
  };
```

Comment: Ah, oui. It works, but can you please explain why? Thanks

Comment: @GAVD Explanation added.