# Pointer to member function with different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

I observed that different GCC versions behave differently when I try to get a pointer to a member function.

```
class Foo {
public:
    void bar() { }
};

int main() {
    void (Foo::*func1)(void) = Foo::bar; // Error with gcc 4.3.2 and gcc 7.1.0

    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles fine with **gcc 4.9.2**(MinGW), **gcc 6.3** and **clang 4.0** on windows.
But results in the following error message with **gcc 4.3.2** and **gcc 7.1.0** (on linux):

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void Foo::bar()'
```

If I change this line to explcitly request the adress via the address operator like so:

```
void (Foo::*func1)(void) = &Foo::bar; // Added an ampersand
```

It compiles **without errors with all tested compilers**.

Please note that there may be the same differences with other versions, this are only the one I could test.

So which one is right?

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326376) question. I know how to fix it. My question is focused on the different compilers and why they behave differently. As fa as I know both variant should be syntactically correct, but different compiler seem to handle that in different ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid use of non-static member function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326376/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-c)

Comment: What do you do with that pointer to a non-static member function? How do you call that function via the pointer without an instance of `Foo`?

Comment: @JimmyB I don't use it because this is just a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I realized that in writing Qt code where you create connections with pointers to non-static member functions. But if I wanted to I could use it like `Foo foo; (foo.* func1)();`

Comment: Didn't know that you could do it like this. Thanks :)

Comment: @JimmyB You're welcome. Not too long ago that I learned it myself :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address-of operator (i.e. `operator&`) is mandatory to form pointers to member function.

It's *optional* for [pointers to non-member function or static member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions), because of the function-to-pointer implicit conversion.

> A pointer to function can be initialized with an address of a non-member function or a static member function. Because of the function-to-pointer implicit conversion, the address-of operator is optional.

But the [function-to-pointer implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer) doesn't apply for non-static member functions.

> An lvalue of function type T can be implicitly converted to a prvalue pointer to that function. This does not apply to non-static member functions because lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist.

BTW: I tried with [Gcc head version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gTWSyefQ1EEVrlUS) and [Clang head version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4l29XxBVmibqPKnf), both failed to compile.

Comment: So gcc 4.9.2, gcc 6.3 and clang 4.0 are wrong? btw. I am allways impressed, if people are able to cite from the standard that fast, great!

Comment: @exilit Yes. I tried it with Gcc and Clang head version, both failed to compile.

Comment: I tried gcc 4.9.2 and gcc 6.3.0 on wandbox and they both fail also. That is somewhat surprising. May it be a compiler flag causing the issue?

Comment: @exilit I'm not sure; I guess it's a bug fixed in newer version.

Comment: You may be right. Interesting enough that my local MinGW gcc 4.9.2 seems to be wrong (copiles) and gcc 4.9.2 on Wandbox seems to be already fixed (fails)

Answer (score 0):

`&` is required to take address of member:

```
&Foo::bar
```

contrary to function which can decay to pointer of function.