# Posix thread in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, pthreads, posix, non-static

I'm getting an error:

> Invalid use of non-static member function

Basically, I need to update the UI in my thread whenever I receive a message:

```
if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, MainWindow::thread_message, &sock))
{
    perror("error in creating the thread");
    // return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

void *MainWindow::thread_message(void *arg)
{
    // UI update, whenever I receive a message from the server.
}
```

Comment: Basic rule of Qt, the GUI should not be updated from a different thread to the main one, check the following link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread , It is also not advisable to use threads in the style of C, Qt offers more friendly ways to do such tasks as QRunnable, QThreadPool, QtConcurrent, QThread:http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html

Comment: The error is caused because pthread_create requires a static method but thread_message is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid use of non-static member function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326376/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-c)

Answer (score 0):

you either need to declare thread_message of class MainWindow static or have a non-class/struct-bound function, as pthread_create requires classic c-style function pointers and there is a difference between those pointers and pointers to class/struct methods in C++.

To overcome that issue C++11 introduced std::thread which accepts both types of function pointers and frees you from having to use platform dependent thread functions in your code.