# invalid use of non-static member function C++ while passing member-function as a function variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, member-functions, pure-virtual

I know similar questions have been asked, but I can't point my finger on my issue. I have a class that has the following method (it is used for multi-threaded programming):

```
  void ServerUtil::WaitForRequst(void (*ProcessRequest)(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp), shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> serv_addr){


 TCPPort tcp_port(serv_addr, true);
 struct sockaddr_in client_addr; //FIXME: add these to a vector so their is a way to track clients


 int i = 0;
 while(i < m_thread_max){
     std::shared_ptr<TCP> tcp = std::make_shared<TCP>(serv_addr, &client_addr, tcp_port, true);
     std::shared_ptr<std::thread> t = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::bind(ProcessRequest, tcp));;
     m_vector_threads.push_back(t);
     i++;
 }


 for(int j = 0; j < m_vector_threads.size();j++)
     m_vector_threads.at(j)->join();
    }

}
```

Now I've created a server class with the following .h file:

class Server{
public:

```
Server(shared_ptr<ServerUtil> serv_util, shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> serv_addr);
virtual void ProcessCommand(char &command) = 0;
//ProcessRequest is the primary thread(client) handler
virtual void ProcessRequest(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp) = 0;
bool SendAck(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp);
bool ReceiveAck(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp);
bool CloseConnection(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp);

protected:
shared_ptr<ServerUtil> m_serv_util;
shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> m_serv_addr;
```

};

And now the following .cpp file for the issue in question:

```
    Server::Server(shared_ptr<ServerUtil> serv_util, shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> serv_addr){

    m_serv_util = serv_util;
    m_serv_addr = serv_addr;
    m_serv_util->WaitForRequst(ProcessRequest, serv_addr);
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
 error: invalid use of non-static member function
 m_serv_util->WaitForRequst(ProcessRequest, m_serv_addr);
```

I also tried commenting out the constructor in the base class and doing this in a derived class (With the pure virtual functions overwritten). Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid use of non-static member function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326376/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-c)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Not quite. This OP doesn't even have pointers-to-members, so that solution is not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
void ServerUtil::WaitForRequst(void (*ProcessRequest)(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp), 
                               shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> serv_addr)
```

`void (*ProcessRequest)(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp)` specifies that the function will be called with a pointer to a function that matches the given `void (shared_ptr<TCP> tcp)` prototype.

```
void ProcessRequest(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp)
```

is a member of `Server` so it really looks more like

```
void ProcessRequest(Server * this, shared_ptr<TCP> tcp)
```

You can sort-of clean that up with

```
void ServerUtil::WaitForRequst(void (Server::*ProcessRequest)(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp), 
                               shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> serv_addr)
```

to let `WaitForRequst` (aside: you have a typo there than may bite you later) know that it will be getting a method of `Server`. But...! you will also have to pass in an object instance for `this`, so

```
void ServerUtil::WaitForRequst(void (Server::*ProcessRequest)(shared_ptr<TCP> tcp), 
                               Server * instance,
                               shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> serv_addr)
```

And this instance needs to be handed to the thread with something like

```
std::shared_ptr<std::thread> t = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::bind(ProcessRequest, 
                                                                    instance, 
                                                                    tcp));
```

`std::thread` will solve the messiness involved with invoking a method pointer for you, but if you are interested, here's a big long discussion on the trials and tribulations of method pointers: [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Unfortunately you are doing stuff there that I think deserves another question. You do not want those `shared_ptr`s. No one is sharing the pointers, so `std::unique_ptr` or no pointer at all should be the go-to. No pointer at all looks to be good here, with the possible exception of `instance` (and consider a re-design if the scope of instance is unreliable or shorter than the thread).

That means

```
void ProcessRequest(TCP tcp)
```

the obligatory

```
void ServerUtil::WaitForRequst(void (Server::*ProcessRequest)(TCP tcp), 
                               Server * instance,
                               shared_ptr<struct sockaddr_in> serv_addr)
```

and

```
 m_vector_threads.emplace_back(ProcessRequest, 
                               instance, 
                               TCP(serv_addr, 
                                   &client_addr, 
                                   tcp_port, 
                                   true));
```

may be sufficient, depending on how well-written `TCP` is. It might be better to pass in all of the parameters and have `ProcessRequest` construct the TCP instance as a local variable. Forgive me if there is a minor syntax error in there. It's not like I have enough to test all this out. Feel free to kick my ass for major syntax errors, though.

Comment: I tried this solution but I still get the same error. I now get that a member function pointer and a non-member function pointer are different, however, the solution above is still using a member function pointer when passed to WaitForRequest.

Comment: @hadis No way you should be getting the same error: https://ideone.com/2hNFVH. Plenty of room for other errors, though.

Comment: It works, thanks! I was calling it incorrectly. Why do I need a reference to Server (as in   util.WaitForRequst(&Server::ProcessRequest, &test, make_shared<sockaddr_in>()); and not   util.WaitForRequst(ProcessRequest, &test, make_shared<sockaddr_in>());)

Comment: @hadis You have to specify `ProcessRequest` is a member of `Server`, that's what the scope resolution `Server::` is for. I don't know why you have to take the address of it. I know that you do, and suspect it's an extra hit of type safety, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler figure out ProcessRequest (when called from within the Server class), that it is an method from Server?

Comment: @hadis it think this is a case of "Because." There may be an awesome reason why the C++ Standard requires it, but I'm afraid I don't know it. Most likely it eliminates a potential problem or two or maybe it's just because the requirement makes the compiler easier to write.